# Run function by step inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays: `pts` and `test`. I need to add objects from `pts` to `test` one by one, after adding new object from `pts` to `test` I need to run function `mimicSvg`.

So I write:

```
var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){

    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    console.log(test);
    test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});
    alert(m);
setTimeout( "mimicSvg(test,1)",3000 );    
  }
```

as you can see I put console.log into this and I see that I get all objects from `pts` to `test` at once. 
How I can add one by one object from `pts` to `test` and after each adding to run function `mimicSvg()`;

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interval timer like this:

```
setTimeout( "mimicSvg(test,1)",m*3000 );
```

Comment: but again I get this in console.log: http://i.imgur.com/EYqXMZc.png as you can see all object from pts is transfered to test at once NOT one by one

Comment: You want to run function after one bye one or want to push the object one by one?

Comment: If you want to push one bye one then use that inside setTimeout() method:

Comment: I want to run function after I add new object from pts to test

Comment: use m*3000 instead of 3000

Comment: this dont work work for me: var test=[{"X":"300","Y":"400"}];
for(var m=1;m<pts.length;m++){
  
    var q = pts[m].X;
    var e = pts[m].Y;
    console.log(test);
    
    
  setTimeout("mimicSvg(test,1); test.push({"X":q,"Y":e})",m*3000 );
    
  }

Comment: I also try: setTimeout(function() {mimicSvg(test,1); test.push({"X":q,"Y":e});},m*3000 );
 but then I execute only test[last_point], test[last_points-1]

Comment: and I have this console.log: http://i.imgur.com/gxwuuT1.png , so as you can see only one object into test ...

Comment: Anybody have idea how to add object from pts to test ONE by ONE, after each adding to run function that use test array?